# html in /src/main/webapp/<folder_name> not found when deployed

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, tomcat7, pom.xml

I'm currently working on this spring-boot application. The application was deployed on a tomcat server using eclipse, I can only access the content of index.html and when I try navigate from **index.html** to **folder_A's index.html**, it will throw the whitelabel error page.

In browser console, there is an error stating that **folder_A** was not found when navigating to folder_A's index.html.

The current structure of my project is:

`````
    Project
     +-- src
     |   +--main
     |   |  +--java (Contains source code)
     |   |  +--resources
     |   |  |  +--application.properties
     |   |  +--webapp
     |   |  |  +--folder_A
     |   |  |  |  +--index.html
     |   |  |  +--WEB_INF
     |   |  |  |  +--web.xml
     |   |  |  +--index.html
     ````
`````

The **web.xml** contains all the servlet mapping from the previous project and the **application.properties** is currently empty.

Why is it happening? Is there any settings I need to configure?

**EDIT**

Added in the pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.sampleproject</groupId>
<artifactId>TestProject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>SpringProject</name>
<description>SpringProject</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <tomcat.version>7.0.75</tomcat.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

```
2017-03-02 08:57:55.467  INFO 8400 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2016 ms
2017-03-02 08:57:55.701  INFO 8400 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-03-02 08:57:55.713  INFO 8400 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-02 08:57:55.713  INFO 8400 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-02 08:57:55.713  INFO 8400 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-02 08:57:55.713  INFO 8400 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-02 08:57:56.135  INFO 8400 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3901d134: startup date [Thu Mar 02 08:57:53 SGT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-03-02 08:57:56.228  INFO 8400 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-03-02 08:57:56.228  INFO 8400 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-03-02 08:57:56.275  INFO 8400 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-03-02 08:57:56.275  INFO 8400 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-03-02 08:57:56.353  INFO 8400 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-03-02 08:57:56.385  INFO 8400 --- [           main] oConfiguration$WelcomePageHandlerMapping : Adding welcome page: ServletContext resource [/index.html]
2017-03-02 08:57:56.572  INFO 8400 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-03-02 08:57:56.697  INFO 8400 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-03-02 08:57:56.853  INFO 8400 --- [           main] c.s.SpringProjectApplication        : Started SpringProjectApplication in 3.883 seconds (JVM running for 4.904)
2017-03-02 08:57:59.355  INFO 8400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/ProjectName]   : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-03-02 08:57:59.355  INFO 8400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-03-02 08:57:59.368  INFO 8400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 13 ms
```

Comment: Care to give more details? Mvn output ? Ppm.xml?

Comment: I've added in the post. Please take a look. Thanks! @asettouf

Comment: The answer is probably in your web.xml or your controllers

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SpringBoot, then you do not need web.xml, and place static files to src/main/resources/static instead of src/main/webapp.

Use the `mvn spring-boot:run` command to start it, do not need to deploy to Tomcat.

This is a [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-static).

Comment: I've tried placing both index.html and folder_A's content in src/main/resources/static already but same thing happened. Just curious, if web.xml is not needed, then where do I do all the servlet mapping?

Comment: Use @Servlet annotation or ServletRegistrationBean, If you still want to use the traditional web.xml, you can refer to this [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-traditional).